# How to customise a wordpress search result?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, ftp, backend

My friend started a blogging website using wordpress for students to write on topics like world affairs, british politics etc. He is a philosophy student so himself doesn't any coding or web development and hence asked me since I'm doing a computer science degree to help him modify the search on his website. Basically the issue is that the search works normally except when you want to use it to search by articles written by a specific author. For example if you write the name of a person, all the articles written by him/her should be displayed. I have no experience in web development but watched loads of videos on youtube on how to customise the search but most of them just show to change its position on the page or just how it looks and none the way I want to specifically customise it. Are there links to any videos on youtube or articles that explain how to do it or what should I do to customise the search in this way? 
I have been telling him for the past week that I will help in because I was confident I would have solved the problem but since I actually started trying the past couple days, I've seen so many ways it could go wrong from ftp to messing up the whole website. I'm sure if it's not clear enough or my question is stupid, I thought for a while before posting this on stack overflow.

Comment: This topic will help you, Actually your question is duplicated and had been answered before. [How to add the author search in the default wordpress search?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131340/how-to-add-the-author-search-in-the-default-wordpress-search)

Answer (score 0):

MODIFY YOUR THEME’S SEARCH.PHP FILE
What we want to do is first take a look at the current search results page. If your theme is not presenting a search bar to make an actual search query, then you can simply append the following to your site’s URL : yoursite.com/?s=your+search+string.

Passing this query will send you to the search results page. Ideally your query should actually produce results so you could try to use a general search phrase that you know will produce multiple results.

Once you have a good idea as to how the results looks now, you can visualize a clear direction as far as how you want it to look. The search.php file usually starts with the following link :

[this link](https://www.shift8web.ca/2016/03/customize-wordpress-search-results-page/)